# How to check if record type is exist in list

Tags: apex, trigger

Can anybody help me how may I check in trigger if object with record type exists based from values from list ?

So I have a list with record types and I would like to check in IF statement if object with this record type currently exists.

```
List<String> recordTypes = new List<String>{'X', 'Z'}
for(object A : listA) {
if(A ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have in the list? RecordType Id, Name, developer Name?
For each record in the Trigger.new variable, you could check for the field recordTypeId, or event recordType.Name or recordType.DeveloperName, and leverage the contains method for collections like List. F.I.

```
List<String> recordTypes = new List<String>{'X', 'Z'}
for(Contact c : Trigger.new) {
  if(recordTypes.contains(c.recordTypeId))
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You cannot reference a parent object field directly from trigger.new. So `c.recordType.Name` will not work, it would be null.

Comment: You are right, that is not a good example, I will edit it. And if needed, you can always query it.